# Programmatically set a partition-key

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

How do I programmatically set a `partition-key` to every instance of a class that I send?

For instance, If I send a `Person`instance, then I want to set the `partition-key` to be `person.getId()`.

```
class Person {
    String id;

    public Person(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class SpringCloudStreamKinesisProducerApplication {

    @InboundChannelAdapter(Source.OUTPUT)
    public Person source() {
        return new Person("my-id-123");
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by setting the id as my-id-123? The broker needs a numeric data as partition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following property to set the partition key:
`spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partitionKeyExpression=payload.id`

That will ensure that any `Person` instance that you are producing will be sent to the corresponding partition on the destination.

Comment: I have set spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.partitionKeyExpression=payload.id
The partitionKey is always "partitionKey-0" How do I set the partition key to a specific value ?

Comment: In addition I have tried setting the header : mysource.getChannel1().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(new Person("messageA", 1)).setHeader("partitionKey", 345).build());  and spring.cloud.stream.bindings.channel1.producer.partitionKeyExpression=headers['partitionKey']   , but the partttion key gets some hash value.